# Can I use all mobile sensors in an ionic app?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

If I develop my app using Ionic, would I be able to use all mobile sensors that I could if I used Android directly instead?

Comment: there are a lot of sensors, which one you want? maybe you need to look at this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/gyroscope/

Comment: also, it is possible to add your own plugin and use it for ionic.